# Understanding CNAME and NS in DNS

Tags: dns, server, cname

I'm trying to learn the different types in DNS (A, CNAME, NS etc).

I do understand what they is used for, but the way I see it, CNAME could be used whenever NS is used, or am I wrong?

For instance:

```
(dns.mysite.example, 192.0.2.4, A)
(mysite.example, dns.mysite.example, CNAME)
```

Would it matter if I used CNAME of NS here?

Also, a second question, am I right in assuming that top level domain (TLD) DNS servers don't have any CNAME records?

Answer (score 11):

No, CNAME and NS are quite different.

CNAME associates an alias with a canonical ("true") name.  So in your example, `dns.mysite.example` would be an alias for canonical/true name `mysite.example`, and all DNS queries for `dns.mysite.example` would be referred to (ie, retried with) `mysite.example`.

NS records identify an authoritative name server for a domain (more correctly, a DNS zone).  They tell a DNS query where to look for authoritative detail about a domain (zone).  Typically, unless you are setting up name server infrastructure, your domain registrar will provide correct NS details for your domain (typically, a few name servers for redundancy, each controlled by your registrar, such as `ns1.registrar.example`, `ns2.registrar.example`).

For subdomains which will resolve to the same address, you do have a choice between A and CNAME records.  The practical difference between A and CNAME records is that CNAME will cause an additional lookup (to resolve the alias to the canonical name) which is not incurred with a direct A record.  So there is a slight performance penalty on lookups if you use CNAME records rather than individual A records for your subdomains.

The root zone file does not contain any CNAME records, but that's not because it can't, but that it doesn't need to.  It mainly contains NS and address (A & AAAA) records for top level domains, for country-code top level domains (and, more recently, for all those new/extended TLDs like .auction).

Comment: Thanks! But if I made a DNS request for mysite.com, I would wind up at 1.2.3.4, right? Isn't that what my example table does? Which would mean it would have the same effect as putting NS?

Comment: How do you define "effect"? An NS would mean that mysite.com is hosted on the dns.mysite.com infrastructure, and that when you you hit mysite.com, the visitor should check for a response for mysite.com with dns.mysite.com infrastructure. 

A CNAME simply says, mysite.com points to dns.mysite.com. Typically, you would not create a CNAME or A Record to dns.mysite.com because that's not an actual website. You would mysite.com, who's Nameservers are dns.mysite.com, and CNAMES would be  a.mysite.com and b.mysite.com. If you hosted yousite.com on the same infrastrucutre, you'd use an A Record.

Comment: " your domain registrar will provide correct NS details for your domain" Only if it provides DNS service for its customer. A domain name registrar and a DNS hosting provider are two completely separate jobs. One company can do both, but they are technically unrelated.